# How to get top of keys from dict by values?

Tags: python

I have dictionary:

```
{ "key1" : 1, "key2" : 2, ...., "key100" : 100 }
```

I want to get list top5 keys by sort values from this dictionary:

```
[ "key100", "key99",.. "key95" ]
```

How to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean with "top 5"? The keys with the highest value? Or the last five keys? If it's the latter, then you can't do this since in Python the order of dicts is not guaranteed.

Comment: your best bet is to create a function with your functionality. You can return either each value or a new dictionary using a dictionary comprehension

Answer (score 5):

Just sort keys using lambda function to return value as key, reversed, and take the 5 first values:

```
d={ "key1" : 1, "key2" : 2, "key3" : 3, "key200" : 200 , "key100" : 100 , "key400" : 400}


print(sorted(d.keys(),reverse=True,key=lambda x : d[x] )[:5])
```

output:

```
['key400', 'key200', 'key100', 'key3', 'key2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = { "key1" : 1, "key2" : 2, ...., "key100" : 100 }
a = sorted(d.values())
a.reverse()
req_list = []
for i in a[:5]:
    req_list.append(d.keys()[d.values().index(i)])

print req_list
```

This would give you the list with greatest 5 values. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: works but clumsy and the performance is very bad on a big list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is there any way to increase the performance? Can I use list comprehension?

Comment: list comprehension is never a way to decrease complexity. problem is that you first sort the values and then for each value, find the keys by index: this search is `O(n)` for each element. I used a sort criteria based on value which is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)

>>> d = {"key1": 1, "key2": 2, "key3": 3, "key98": 98 , "key99": 99 , "key100": 100}

>>> sorted(d, reverse=True, key=d.get)[:3]
['key100', 'key99', 'key98']
```